# Derivate from Coupon collector: coupons with different probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, coupon-collector

I am struggling to find the expectation of a derivate of the Coupon collector's problem

In the description of my problem, I will write down some number but each of them are not fix, I am searching a general solution

There is 4 packets:

- A with 40 coupons
- B with 30 coupons
- C with 20 coupons
- D with 10 coupons

All the 100 coupons are differents.

At each draw, we draw a coupon from a random packet. And then put the coupon back in this packet.

In the random choice of the packet, each packet have it own probability to be selected:

- A is selected 60% of the time
- B is selected 20% of the time
- C is selected 15% of the time
- D is selected 5% of the time

My problem is to calculate the probability to see all the 100 coupons in n draws.
And the expectation of the number of draw needed to se all the 100 coupons

It seem related to this question:
[Expected number of rolls for an unfair die to get all possibile values at least once](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793253/expected-number-of-rolls-for-an-unfair-die-to-get-all-possibile-values-at-least?rq=1)
(it's the problem with 2 packet, one with 2,3,4,5,6 and one with 1, the first packet have 5/7 to be picked and the second 2/7) But the solution doesn't have any explanation and I have difficulty to understand from where it come

Thank you

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139007/discussion-on-question-by-zeldarck-derivate-from-coupon-collector-coupons-with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part 3.2 of this document bring an answer and a formula to calculate the expectation

https://mat.uab.cat/matmat_antiga/PDFv2014/v2014n02.pdf